# SSRS Bubble Chart X-Axis not visible

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi-paginated-reports

i have a problem with my ssrs report. The X-Axis is not showing no matter what settings i change. I have no idea. When i change the start and end to 0 and 5 (including 0), the X-Axis is not visible. Any ideas are appreciated!

I am not able to upload the screenshot to this post directly atm there is a server error but you can find it here https://ibb.co/fCKzd69